# How to add value dynamically in a TableModel Qt

Tags: qt, qml

I have this TableModel :

```
TableView {
       id : tableview_
       anchors.fill: parent
       columnSpacing: 1
       rowSpacing: 1
       clip : true

       model : TableModel {
           id : table_model
           TableModelColumn {display : "temps"}
           TableModelColumn {display: "x"}
           TableModelColumn {display: "y"}
           TableModelColumn {display: "theta"}

           rows: [
               {"temps" : "temps",
                   "x":"x",
                   "y" :"y",
                   "theta":"theta"}]
       }
       delegate: Rectangle {
           implicitWidth: 90
           implicitHeight: 100
           border.width: 1

           Text {
               text: display
               font.pixelSize: 20
               anchors.centerIn: parent
           }
       }
}
```

And I wanted to add dynamically every 0.5 seconds values that I get from measures :

```
Timer
    {
        interval: 500
        repeat: false
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            table_model.insertRow(table_model.rowCount);
            table_model.setData(table_model.rowCount-1, "0,5" , "temps");
            table_model.setData(table_model.rowCount-1, data_pendule.getX(), "x");
            table_model.setData(table_model.rowCount-1, data_pendule.getX(), "y");
            table_model.setData(table_model.rowCount-1, data_pendule.getTheta(), "theta");
        }
     }
```

And I don't understand why it doesn't work. Originally I exchanged my rows and my columns but I figured out that it maybe was more simple to add rows dynamically than refresh values in existant cells.
Can you help me?

Comment: [insertRow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-tablemodel.html#insertRow-method) has 2 arguments, the second one is a new object that you want to insert. or use `appendRow` instead but still it requires an object. Also the `setData`'s first argument's type is `QModelIndex` not int.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I write the triggered like this : `table_model.insertRow(table_model.rowCount,{"temps":"0,5","x":data_pendule.getX(),"y":data_pendule.getY(),"theta":data_pendule.getTheta()});`

Comment: Fine, as I said you can use appendRow if you insert you object at the end of list.